# Python - Embedding a SSH Terminal or send commands to Tkinter Frame Terminal

Tags: python, ssh, tkinter, terminal

I am using the following code from a previous solution:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
termf = Frame(root, height=400, width=500)

termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = termf.winfo_id()
os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 40x20 -sb &' % wid)

root.mainloop()
```

Now I'd like to start this with an ssh into another PC by default.  I feel like it's a  modification of the os.system line to possibly combine commands but I can't quite get it.

If it's not possible to auto-launch the terminal into a ssh session, then what is the proper way to write/insert to a Tkinter Frame?  Using the documentation, it has no write/insert function.

I'm unfamiliar with attaching objects to frames but the idea is to have an ssh session auto-start.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Read tag descriptions before adding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use xterm's `-e "command to execute"` option to execute a command in the xterm on startup:

```
os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 40x20 -sb -e "ssh somehost" &' % wid)
```

Comment: That is definitely the start of what I'm looking for.  Of course it prompts to a password so I'll have to figure out how to incorporate pexpect in this.

Still begs the question is there a  termf.write("command") so I could take care of this problem?  I know that's Tkinter related with having a Frame and writing input.

Comment: @user3000724 You could probably use `subprocess.Popen()` to spawn a child process for the xterm and then write to the process' STDIN to feed it the password, but that sounds like a separate question from this one to me. Or, if you have control over both hosts, just setup SSH keys for passwordless login. Again though, probably out of the scope of this question.